# AngularJS Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode in ie 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I'm have problem with working `angular js` in `ie 11`

> TypeError: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode at link (`ves-min.js:490:7`) at `Anonymous function` (angular.js:7079:34)`enter code here` at `nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6677:13)` at `compositeLinkFn (angular.js:6071:13`) at `publicLinkFn (angular.js:5967:30)` at link `(angular-route.js:919:7)` at `boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:6091:9)`

Please help me some solution, thanks.

Comment: Can you use the non-minified version of your code and post the relevant part in your code it is complaining about?

Comment: Hi @Le Toan, Your question is too vague to understand where is the exact problem. Can you please provide more details like code snapshot, what is not working etc. I do use AngularJS in IE11 and it works well. Hence it won't be appropriate to say AngularJS not working in IE11. Please provide complete details about your problem.

Answer (score 14):

Add this line in your head tag and do refresh, when It will ask for "allow block content" click "yes".

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

Comment: For future searchers - this solution combined with moving the script for the app.js to the bottom i.e. <script  type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/app/app.js"></script> should be the last script (apologies I can't find the place on SO where someone pointed this out.  The 2 actions combined solved a 'nightmare' issue for me!

Answer (score 11):

It could be the following problem:

[AngularJS controllers and "use strict"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957625/angularjs-controllers-and-use-strict/12966954#12966954)

Maybe it's just that IE 11 respects strict mode, which means if you do something like:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function webAddressController($scope, $rootScope, web_address_service) {
        // Do things
    }

}());
```

The `webAddressController`function is not in global scope for Angular to pick (the point of using the self executing syntax is to avoid adding things to global scope).

So, you might want to try something like:

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('myApp').controller('webAddressController', function($scope) {
        // Do things
    });

}(window.angular));​
```

Comment: Thanks Meligy, i'm fixed ok now.

Comment: Well, would you please mark the answer then? :)
Thanks!

Comment: (By that I meant clicking the tick you'll see in front of the answer, THANKS!)