# Angular JS not working for IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used Angular 1.5.x and it works in Chrome but not in IE11.
Here is the error it throws in IE11

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'module'
```

This happens in following line

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

I have already tried with this workaround

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Above solution does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351713/angular-js-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: Thanks it worked with my solution above. I was trying with developer mode on and probably it was not working because of that.