# deploying angular to weblogic

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse

I have an angular app that works absolutely fine on Eclipse (Neon) + Tomcat environment.

But when I export the project as a WAR file and deploy it on a Weblogic server (10.3.6) it does not load the app. It doesn't throw any error message as well. It just gives me a blank page on IE without loading any of the contents of the html.

It looks like I am missing some kind of configuration while exporting this to weblogic as a WAR file. How can I fix this?

Sample Code - index.html

```
<html ng-app="testapp" lang="en">
<head>
<title>New App</title>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
{{var}}
</body>
</html>

controller.js

var app = angular.module('testapp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.var = 'wat2do';
});
```

Comment: Did you look in the weblogic log files?  Without more detail, it is anybody's guess.

Comment: Did you look in the *browser's* console output? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks but there is nothing on the logs to indicate a problem... It looks to me like it has not recognized the app as angular. When I use a {{var}} it prints it as it is rather than the $scope.var defined in the controller.js. So I think I am missing something in defining the web-app as angular.

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with ie11. Adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" /> within <head> solved this problem. 
Solution from page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351713/angular-js-not-working-in-ie-11
Thanks @Shyam_coder